# Pandas pivot table ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below (top 3 rows):

```
Sample_Name Sample_ID   Sample_Type IS  Component_Name  IS_Name Component_Group_Name    Outlier_Reasons Actual_Concentration    Area    Height  Retention_Time  Width_at_50_pct Used    Calculated_Concentration    Accuracy
Index                                                               
1   20170824_ELN147926_HexLacCer_Plasma_A-1-1   NaN Unknown True    GluCer(d18:1/12:0)_LCB_264.3    NaN NaN NaN 0.1 2.733532e+06    5.963840e+05    2.963911    0.068676    True    NaN NaN
2   20170824_ELN147926_HexLacCer_Plasma_A-1-1   NaN Unknown True    GluCer(d18:1/17:0)_LCB_264.3    NaN NaN NaN 0.1 2.945190e+06    5.597470e+05    2.745026    0.068086    True    NaN NaN
3   20170824_ELN147926_HexLacCer_Plasma_A-1-1   NaN Unknown False   GluCer(d18:1/16:0)_LCB_264.3    GluCer(d18:1/17:0)_LCB_264.3    NaN NaN NaN 3.993535e+06    8.912731e+05    2.791991    0.059864    True    125.927659773487    NaN
```

When trying to generate a pivot table:

```
pivoted_report_conc = raw_report.pivot(index = "Sample_Name", columns = 'Component_Name', values = "Calculated_Concentration")
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

I tried resetting the index but it did not help. I couldn't find any duplicate values in the "Index" column. Could someone please help identify the problem here?

The expected output would be a reshaped dataframe with only the unique component names as columns and respective concentrations for each sample name:

```
Sample_Name    GluCer(d18:1/12:0)_LCB_264.3    GluCer(d18:1/17:0)_LCB_264.3    GluCer(d18:1/16:0)_LCB_264.3
20170824_ELN147926_HexLacCer_Plasma_A-1-1    NaN    NaN    125.927659773487
```

To clarify, I am not looking to aggregate the data, just reshape it.

Comment: The sample name that you are using as index in your pivot code is same for all the three rows. You need pivot_table with appropriate aggfunc to aggregate the data

Comment: It'd be helpful to update your post with expected output.

Comment: Thanks @andrew_reece. I have updated the post to reflect the desired output.

Comment: What version of Pandas and Python are you using?  With Pandas 0.20.3 and Python 3.6, and your given sample data, even if I explicitly make duplicates in the initial index with `df.index = [1,1,2]`, your `pivot()` statement produces your expected output.

Comment: @andrew_reece I am using Pandas 0.19.2 and Python 2.7.13  I can try to update the package to see if it helps.

Comment: No need, I realized the problem.  Your example case works because the `Calculated_Concentration` only has one non-`NaN` value.  If you have more than one non-`NaN` value for a given `Sample_Name`, what do you expect the pivoted `Calculated_Concentration` value to be?  J-Eubanks's answer has the right of it (although you can just use `pivot()` instead of `pivot_table()`).

Comment: I am trying to pivot on Sample_Name, so I expected the NaN Calculated_Concentration values for each Component_Name to just align with the respective columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `groupby()` and `unstack()` to get around the error you're seeing with `pivot()`.

Here's some example data, with a few edge cases added, and some column values removed or substituted for [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
# df
      Sample_Name  Sample_ID     IS Component_Name Calculated_Concentration Outlier_Reasons
Index                                                                    
1             foo        NaN   True              x                  NaN              NaN  
1             foo        NaN   True              y                  NaN              NaN 
2             foo        NaN   False             z            125.92766              NaN 
2             bar        NaN   False             x                 1.00              NaN  
2             bar        NaN   False             y                 2.00              NaN  
2             bar        NaN   False             z                  NaN              NaN  

(df.groupby(['Sample_Name','Component_Name'])
   .Calculated_Concentration
   .first()
   .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
Component_Name    x   y          z
Sample_Name                       
bar             1.0 2.0        NaN
foo             NaN NaN  125.92766
```

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to accomplish what you are looking to do by using the the `pandas.pivot_table()` functionality as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html).

With your dataframe stored as `df` use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('table_from_which_to_read')

new_df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Simple Name'], columns = 'Component_Name', values = "Calculated_Concentration")
```

If you want something other than the mean of the concentration value, you will need to change the `aggfunc` parameter.

**EDIT**

Since you don't want to aggregate over the values, you can reshape the data by using the `set_index` function on your DataFrame with documentation found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'NonUniqueLabel':['Item1','Item1','Item1','Item2'],
     'SemiUniqueValue':['X','Y','Z','X'], 'Value':[1.0,100,5,None])

new_df = df.set_index(['NonUniqueLabel','SemiUniqueLabel'])
```

The resulting table should look like what you expect the results to be and will have a multi-index.